# react css imported in jsx module not applied

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I import my css file like:

```
import styles from "./Documentation.module.css";
```

Use the style here:

```
<button
    className={styles.button}
    onClick={(e) => selectDoc(m.id)}
    >
    <b>{m.title}</b>
</button>
```

The css for the button looks like:

```
.button {
    color: "#d0e6a5";
    background-color: "#5d684b";
    border: "none";
    border-left: "4px solid #d0e6a5";
    font-size: "28px";
    padding: "6px 12px";
    margin: "3px";
    width: "200px";
}
```

but the css doesnt get applied to the button element. This happens to all styles. I have no more idea what the proplem could be.

Using inlined or "style" is no option for me here, sice the css will get a bunch more.
Any idea how i could diagnose the problem here?

Comment: You need bundlers like webpack or rollup to make CSS imports work. Do you use them?

Comment: You need to have react-scripts@2.0.0 and higher to use this feature i.e CSS Modules Stylesheet

Comment: @VladislavKibenko i run my app with npm start in debug. in release, i build it. tbh i dont know since my knownledge is limited still.

Comment: @BilalNasir package.json tells me i use react-scripts `6.3.0

Comment: Could you `console.log(styles)` to make sure, webpack correctly imports this CSS? In case, it is not, check if you typed correct imported file name

Comment: You have to name the css file as Documentation.module.css. Are you doing so ?

Comment: @VladislavKibenko i have the following console output https://prnt.sc/geQZC0x-5KtX so i would guess it is imported correct. do i asume correctly?

Comment: @BilalNasir the file is indeed correctly named. also the console.log seems like it is correctly imported

Comment: Do you see this file content attached to `<head/>` part of html document? Try to replace `.module.css` postfix with `.css`

Comment: @VladislavKibenko there is something in the head. see the quick screenshot. i in the meantime give the file rename a try https://prnt.sc/T0XGsVxW1iO6 --addendum: removing the .module  the random number postfixes in the screenshot are removed, but the console log object is different now (no values i could recognize)

Comment: CSS file seems to be inserted correctly. Check now if `button` in your html has class name provided in screenshot

Comment: the button now does not have a classname attached (in the browser) https://prnt.sc/_sEzEgDIPNrl

Comment: Then, `styles.button` is probably undefined for some reason. Could show what `console.log(styles)` outputs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250548/discussion-between-ranndom-and-vladislav-kibenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in the css file the syntax is incorrect. You dont have to put quotes in he values. Try to replace it with the following css

```
.button {
color: #d0e6a5;
background-color: #5d684b;
border: none;
border-left: 4px solid #d0e6a5;
font-size: 28px;
padding: 6px 12px;
margin: 3px;
width: 200px;}
```

Comment: your point is correct. but it doesnt fix my problem. but i indeed now did fix my css.

Comment: in the end it was indeed the faulty css.. credits to you. my mistake why i didnt spot it right away, i removed the .module from the css filename.

Comment: also big credit to @Vladislav Kibenko he helped out a lot by deagnosing the proplem.